# tidyr spread subset of key-value pairs

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

Given the example data, I'd like to `spread` a subset of the `key-value` pairs.  In this case it is just one pair.  However there are other cases where the subset to be `spread` is more than one pair.

```
library(tidyr)
# dummy data
> df1 <- data.frame(e = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
              n = c("a", "b", "c", "d") ,
              s = c(1, 2, 5, 7))
> df1
  e n s
1 1 a 1
2 1 b 2
3 1 c 5
4 1 d 7
```

Classical spread of all key-value pairs:

```
> df1 %>% spread(n,s)

  e a b c d
1 1 1 2 5 7
```

Desired output, spread only `n=c`

```
  e c n s
1 1 5 a 1
2 1 5 b 2
3 1 5 d 7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do a `gather` after the `spread`

```
df1 %>%
  spread(n, s) %>% 
  gather(n, s, -c, -e)
#  e c n s
#1 1 5 a 1
#2 1 5 b 2
#3 1 5 d 7
```

---

Or instead of `spread/gather`, we `filter` without the 'c' row and then `mutate` to create the 'c' column while subsetting the 's' that corresponds to 'c'

```
df1 %>% 
   filter(n != "c") %>% 
   mutate(c = df1$s[df1$n=="c"])
```